# How to prevent division by zero in this query?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I prevent division by zero in the following query?

```
TRUNCATE(abs((((sum(date(timestamp) = curdate()) - sum((timestamp BETWEEN concat(date(date_add(now(), interval -1 day)), ' 00:00:00')
AND 
date_sub(now( ), interval 24 hour)))) / ((sum(date(timestamp) = curdate()) + 
sum((timestamp BETWEEN concat(date(date_add(now(), interval -1 day)), ' 00:00:00')
AND 
date_sub(now( ), interval 24 hour))))/2))*100)),0) AS percentage_diff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 0 in this sample I assigne 1

```
truncate(abs((((SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - SUM((TIMESTAMP 
    between CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)), ' 00:00:00') 
    and DATE_SUB(NOW( ), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)))) / 

     if (
          (( sum(date(timestamp) = curdate()) + 
               SUM((TIMESTAMP between CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)), ' 00:00:00') 
               and DATE_SUB(NOW( ), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))))/2)  = 0, 1 ,
          ((sum(date(timestamp) = curdate()) + 
               SUM((TIMESTAMP between CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)), ' 00:00:00') 
               and DATE_SUB(NOW( ), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))))/2) 
    )
    )*100)),0) as percentage_diff
```

Comment: update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. the condition  if (( curdate....  /2) = 0, 1 , ....) check for zero so is  strange  that is happend ..  but you have a comparision   `sum(date(timestamp) = curdate()`  .. is this right?  .but try also .check for result in the denominator in a separeted  select